# How to access properties in domain object statistics tab?

Tags: ocean, petrel

It would be helpful for me to access values in the statistics tab of pillar grids and horizons.  I can calculate much of it myself, but if these properties exist somewhere it would be much easier if I could just access them instead.

Comment: Sorry.  Posted prematurely.  Found it in the documentation.  Just had to use StatisticsService.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The StatisticsService and the Statistics class should provide you with most of the information you need.

Answer (score 1):

You can find details on the use of it in Volume #9 of the Ocean Developers Guide. It's the Petrel Customization volume.